# Cannot access Ambari UI

Tags: networking, server, iptables, telnet

I installed Ambari server and agent on the same instance just to make tests. The problem is that I cannot access Ambari UI on port 8080. I tried running `telnet 172.xx.xx.xx 8080`, but there is no connection.

I setup `etc/hosts` and `etc/hostname` as follows:

```
/etc/hosts
172.xx.xx.xx ambarimaster1 ambarimaster1.local.test.org ambarimaster1

/etc/hostname
ambarimaster1
```

I checked `iptables`:

```
service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status iptables.service
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.